# How to select a div within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to take the contents of a div within an iframe, delete the iframe, and display only  the div. I can't figure out why this won't work- I am not sure of whether to use contentWindow or contentDocument.. Any pointers? Thanks!

I have one div with id "iframe", within that the iframe with id "embedded_article",

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getContentFromIframe()

{    
var parent = document.getElementById('iframe');
var child = document.getElementById('embedded_article');

var oldContent = child.contentWindow.document.innerHTML;

var newContent = child.contentWindow.document.getElementById('ec-article').innerHTML;

  document.getElementById('iframe').removeChild(document.getElementById('embedded_article'));


parent.innerHTML = newContent;    

}
</script>
```

Comment: this is generally not allowed by browsers, as it is unsafe.

Comment: @tekknolagi What he's trying to do is allowed as long as the frames share the same domain. This just isn't the right way to do it. `document.getElementById('iframe')` returns an `iframe` element in the outer window, not a `document` or `window` object inside the frame, so it doesn't have children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').removeChild(document.getElementById('embedded_article'));
```

Should look something like:

```
var element = frames['iframe'].document.getElementById('embedded_article');

element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

`window.frames['yourFrameId']` evaluates to the `window` object associated with your frame. when you use `document.getElementById`, you want to use the `document` belonging to your frame's `window`, not the `document` in your main window. The rest should be self-explanitory.

Answer (score 2):

to get to the div inside an iFrame you can try something like this

```
     var div = document.getElementById("YourIFrameID").contentWindow.document.body.getElementById("YOUR_DIV_ID")
```

Comment: this isn't working, just says that the first document.getElementById( ... ) is empty